# Have read_html read cell content and tooltip (text bubble) separately, instead of concatenate them

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, tooltip

This site [page](https://stats.gladiabots.com/pantheon?) has tooltips appearing when hovering over values in columns `"Score"` and `"XP LVL"`.

It appears that `read_html` will concatenate **cell content** and **tooltip**. Splitting those in post-processing is not always obvious and I seek a way to have `read_html` handle them separately, possibly return them as two columns.

This is how the first row appears online:

| (Rank)# | Name | Score | XP LVL | Victories / Total | Victory Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rainin☆☆☆☆ | 6129 | 447 | 408 / 531 | 76% |

- where `"Score"`'s "6129" carries tooltip "Max6129"
- where, more annoyingly, `"XP LVL"`'s "447" carries tooltip "21173534 pts"

This is how it appears after reading:

```
pd.read_html('https://stats.gladiabots.com/pantheon?', header=0, flavor="html5lib")[0]

        #            Name         Score           XP LVL Victories / Total  \
0       1      Rainin☆☆☆☆  6129Max 6129  44721173534 pts         408 / 531
```

See "44721173534 pts" is the concatenation of "447" and "21173534 pts". `"XP LVL"` values have a variable number of digits, so splitting the string in the post-processing phase would require being pretty smart about it and I woud like to explore the "*let read_html do the split*", first.

(The special flavor="html5lib" was added because the page is dynamically-generated)

I have not found any mention of tooltips in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is because pandas uses the `.text` attribute of the `<td>` `bs4.element.Tag` objects and this one concatenate (*without any separator*) the texts of all the tag's children.

In the first row of the table, the score has two children `6129` and `Max 6129`, thus the concat.

```html
<td nowrap="" class="barContainer">
  <div class="scoreBar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  <div class="maxScoreBar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
  <span class="barLabel tooltipable">
    "6129"
    <span class="tooltip">
      "Max 6129"
    </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

A quick/hacky solution would be to override the [`_text_getter`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e86ed377639948c64c429059127bcf5b359ab6be/pandas/io/html.py#L628) method of the parser used by pandas and replace `.text` with [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)  that has a `separator` parameter :

```
def _text_getter(self, obj):
    return obj.get_text(separator="_", strip=True) # I choosed "_"

pd.io.html._BeautifulSoupHtml5LibFrameParser._text_getter = _text_getter
```

With this modification, [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) gives this `df` :

```
        #            Name          Score            XP LVL Victories / Total Victory_Ratio
0       1      Rainin☆☆☆☆  6129_Max 6129  447_21173534 pts         408 / 531           76%
1       2        ZM_XL☆☆☆  5888_Max 6025  344_15942978 pts       3685 / 6748           54%
2       3     UzuraGames☆  5555_Max 5586   119_4688941 pts        610 / 1109           55%
..    ...             ...            ...               ...               ...           ...
997   998          Tekuma  3183_Max 3460     27_370585 pts         151 / 304           49%
998   999            hemi  3183_Max 3227      10_49432 pts           29 / 62           46%
999  1000  wanna bet kid?  3183_Max 3304      13_85777 pts           51 / 95           53%

[1000 rows x 6 columns]
```

And this way, you can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) / disattach the values of the two concerned columns :

```
scores = df.pop("Score").str.extract(r"(?P<Score>\d+)_Max (?P<Max>\d+)")
xplvls = df.pop("XP LVL").str.extract(r"(?P<XPLVL>\d+)_(?P<PTS>\d+)")

out = pd.concat([df, scores, xplvls], axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out) # with only `scores` and `xplvls`

    Score   Max XPLVL       PTS
0    6129  6129   447  21173534
1    5888  6025   344  15942978
2    5555  5586   119   4688941
..    ...   ...   ...       ...
997  3183  3460    27    370585
998  3183  3227    10     49432
999  3183  3304    13     85777

[1000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the nice "simple" hack. So pandas uses beautifulsoup inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to parse the page and then create the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stats.gladiabots.com/pantheon"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html5lib")

all_data = []
for tr in soup.table.select("tr:has(td)"):
    all_data.append([])
    for td in tr.select("td"):
        all_data[-1].extend(td.get_text(strip=True, separator="###").split("###"))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["#", "Name", "Score", "Score2", "XP LVL", "PTS", "V/T", "Ratio"]
)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   #          Name Score    Score2 XP LVL           PTS          V/T Ratio
0  1    Rainin☆☆☆☆  6129  Max 6129    447  21173534 pts    408 / 531   76%
1  2      ZM_XL☆☆☆  5888  Max 6025    344  15942978 pts  3685 / 6748   54%
2  3   UzuraGames☆  5555  Max 5586    119   4688941 pts   610 / 1109   55%
3  4  Markolainen☆  5521  Max 5612    113   4433827 pts   763 / 1255   60%
4  5     Defunct☆☆  5337  Max 5452    225   9999855 pts  1535 / 3066   50%
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you for the crash course on BeautifulSoup!

Comment: Choosing the answer to accept was difficult. Since I asked for "have read_html" do the work, I accepted Timeless's answer. I note that for other readers, your answer might be more useful though.

Answer (score 0):

To  handle read_html  the text bubbles separately, you can use the BeautifulSoup package to parse the HTML and extract the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stats.gladiabots.com/pantheon'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = []
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols) == 0:
        continue
    score = cols[2].text.split('Max')[0]
    xp_lvl = cols[3].text.split(' pts')[0]
    data.append([cols[0].text, cols[1].text, score, xp_lvl, cols[4].text, cols[5].text])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Rank', 'Name', 'Score', 'XP LVL', 'Victories / Total', 'Victory Ratio'])
```

Here I assumes that the "Score" column always has the "Max" text bubble, and the "XP LVL" column always has the " pts" text bubble. If this is not the case, you may need to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Returns empty data. Have you obtained the desired output yourself?